# How do I multiply from a input variable?

Tags: python, input, numbers

I am having trouble figuring out how to multiply my users input.

I have tried changing the functions of the variables for 'int' to 'float' and to 'str' but i cant seem to figure it out. My code:

```
pops = input("Enter your favorite pop: ")
cost = input("Enter how much they cost: ")
how_many = input("Enter how many pops you have: ")

print('My favorite pop is ' + pops + '!')
print('They cost about ' + cost + ' dollars.')
print('I have about ' + how_many + ' pops!')

result = str(cost) * str(how_many)

print("You have spent over " + result + " dollars on pops!")
```

I've got next error:

> result = str(cost) * str(how_many)
>   TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: You want to convert those variables to integers, not strings.  (They're strings already.) `result = int(cost) * int(how_many)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to multiply two strings.
You should multiply like this:

`result = float(cost) * int(how_many)`

But don't forget to reconvert the result to string in the last line or it will give you another error (`TypeError` in this case)

`print("You have spent over " + str(result) + " dollars on pops!")`

Comment: I might add that you can check if a string is made of digits (to avoid the `ValueError` mentioned by @fendall) with the string built-in method `isdigit()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I **highly recommend** you to start with some guides/tutorials or at least read [official python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) to get in touch with language basics.

Regarding your problem. I'll show you basic algorithm how to use official docs to find solution.

1. Let's check docs of [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function.

   > The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string, and returns that.

   Strings in python are represented as [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str). So, after execution of `input()` variables `pops`, `cost` and `how_many` contains `str` values.
2. In your code you're using [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) function. Let's check in docs what does this function perform:

   > Return a [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) version of object.

   Now you understand that expressions `str(cost)` and `str(how_many)` convert `str` to `str` which means .. do nothing.
3. How to multiply values from input?

   You need to multiply two values, which requires converting `str` to one of [numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

   For `cost` we will use `float`, cause it can contain fractional number. For `how_many` we can use `int` cause count normally is integer. To convert `str` to numbers we will use [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) and [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) functions.

   In your code you need just edit line where error occurred and replace useless call of `str()` with proper functions:

   ```
   result = float(cost) * int(how_many)
   ```

   Result of multiplication `float` and `int` will be `float`.
4. How to print result?

   Code you're using will throw an error, cause you can't sum `str` and `float`. There're several ways how to print desired message:

   1. Convert `result` to `str`.

      It's the most obvious way - just use `str()` function:

      ```
      print("You have spent over " + str(result) + " dollars on pops!")
      ```
   2. Use features of [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function:

      In docs written:

      > **print(** **objects*, *sep=' '*, *end='\n'*, *file=sys.stdout*, *flush=False* **)**
      >
      > Print *objects* to the text stream *file*, separated by *sep* and followed by *end*.

      As we see, default separator between objects is space, so we can just list start of string, `result` and ending in arguments of `print()` function:

      ```
      print("You have spent over", result, "dollars on pops!")
      ```
   3. [String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

      It's very complex topic, you can read more information by following provided link, I'll just show you one of methods using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function:

      ```
      print("You have spent over {} dollars on pops!".format(result))
      ```

Answer (score 0):

`str(item)` converts `item` to a string. Similarly, `float(item)` converts `item` to a float (if possible).

The code:

```
result = float(cost) * int(how_many)
```

will not produce the same error as you indicated occurred, but may introduce a `ValueError`, if the input given is not what you are expecting.

Example:

```
a = "b"
float(a)
```

**Output**

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

result = int(cost) * int(how_many) can fix the issue. Cost and how_many are non-numeric and converting them to int gives the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
pops = input("Enter your favorite pop: ")
cost = input("Enter how much they cost: ")
how_many = input("Enter how many pops you have: ")

print('My favorite pop is ' + pops + '!')
print('They cost about ' + cost + ' dollars.')
print('I have about ' + how_many + ' pops!')

result = float(cost) * int(how_many)

print("You have spent over " + str(result) + " dollars on pops!")
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are trying to convert the cost to a string, conversion from one type to another except when using the bool() is illegal. That is why the program is raising a TypeError.

```
pops = input("Enter your favorite pop: ")
cost = input("Enter how much they cost: ")
how_many = input("Enter how many pops you have: ")

print('My favorite pop is ' + pops + '!')
print('They cost about ' + cost + ' dollars.')
print('I have about ' + how_many + ' pops!')

result = cost * how_many 

print("You have spent over " + result + " dollars on pops!"
```

Comment: The statement "conversion from one type to another except when using the bool() is illegal" is false. Example ```int("3")``` will return 3. In addition this is not why the code is raising a TypeError.